# calling constructor of VSTO Addin (thisaddin class) from a C# application

Tags: c#, com, vsto

I have a VSTO addin which I want to invoke from a C# EXE. thisaddin.designer.cs file has a constructor as below.

Collapse | Copy Code

```
public ThisAddIn(global::Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.ApplicationFactory factory, global::System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : 
          base(factory, serviceProvider, "AddIn", "ThisAddIn") {
        Globals.Factory = factory;
    }
```

I have added the reference of Addin to my C# project and tried the below. But, not sure what arguments to pass.

Collapse | Copy Code

```
MTMWordAddIn.ThisAddIn addin = new MTMWordAddIn.ThisAddIn(null, null);
```

Kindly suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. Exactly what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to launch VSTO Addin DLL using my C# application. Please suggest.

Comment: Is this addin meant for deployment at large or for internal use?

Comment: I want to create 3 seperate VSTO DLL's for different word versions (2007, 2010 & 2013). Use my EXE to invoke these DLL's after a Word version check on the client system. I don't want to deploy the VSTO Addin as Setup.exe. Rather I want to use my EXE to launch the VSTO dll's.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the approach above would work.
I would rather make the exe to check for Word version and just change the vsto name in the registry entry.

When you install VSTO the registry will be added here

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins
```

These registry key should have Manifest String Key and Value should be the path of the VSTO file.
Your exe can look for the Word version and change the path in the registry entries.(This might need permission if the key is in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).

Or rather use [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) which is compatible from Word 2000 to 2013